# how to loop in function in pyspark and pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have pyspark/pandas dataframe given below, assign different value for each level now I want according to level in column it take value and calculate end result. here I tried somoething.
I tried in pyspark and python both

```
    column
+-------------------+
|            lower  |
|              upper|
|           dropper |
|           dropper |
|           lower   |
+-------------------+
```

```py
current_id = 70
def fun(i):
    for i in df.select('level').distinct().collect():
        print(i)
        if i == 'dropper':
            runid = 12
              
        elif i == 'upper':
            runid = 36
                 
        else i != 'dropper' or 'upper':
             runid = 24
fun('lower')
duration = current_id - runid
print(duration)
```

Comment: You can do it in pandas, but in PySpark it's not ok to try to do loops.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Pandas as well. You want to avoid loops and use vectorized functions more.  In Pandas, assigning the different value, you can look for `replace` or `map` function. In PySpark, it will be `when` and `otherwise`. https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/